# Not showing multiple markers MAP API

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-maps

I am making a web, and I have a list of location, and I want to display all the marker in those location.

Here is my code:

```
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
          geoLoc = navigator.geolocation;
          var user_list = [];
          watchID = geoLoc.watchPosition(function showLocation(position) {
          var lat = position.coords.latitude;
          var lng = position.coords.longitude;
          var today = new Date();
          var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
          var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
          var dateTime = date+' '+time;
          fStore.collection("User").doc(userID).update({
            latitude: lat,
            longitutde: lng,
            time: dateTime
          })
          fStore.collection("User").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                if (doc.id != userID){
                    // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                    user_list.push(doc.data());
                    console.log(user_list);
                    console.log(user_list.length);
                }
            });

            for (var i = 0; i < user_list.length; i++){
                console.log("can you?");
                createMarker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(user_list[i][2], user_list[i][3]),
                    map: map,
                    title: user_list[i][0]
                  });
                  console.log("drawn?")
            }
        })

    }, errorHandler,  {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 5000,
        maximumAge: 0
    });
}
```

I try to do console.log in the code to see if it runs and it returns those console log as well but no marker are drawn.

This is a sample of a record in the list:

```
user_list= [{
address: "test"
email: "lalala@gmail.com"
first_name: "test"
last_name: "test"
latitude: 39.9572992
longitutde: -75.2091136
time: "2020-5-16 23:51:6"
userID: "gV2hZe1wf3f9FF00r3apYpKSb743"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the way you accessing object.. You need `dot(.)` operator, to access value from object.`user_list[i].latitude`

```
for (var i = 0; i < user_list.length; i++) {
  console.log("can you?");
  createMarker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(user_list[i].latitude, user_list[i].longitutde), // Here, 
    map: map,
    title: user_list[i].address,
  });
  console.log("drawn?");
}
```

You can simplify using `forEach`:

```
user_list.forEach((user) => {
  createMarker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(user.latitude, user.longitutde),
    map: map,
    title: user.address,
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried, it does not have any error but still does not draw any marker on the map. I already have a marker of my location on the map, is there any chance this is the cause?